# How to create a dependency on SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure, `sp1`, which has two input parameters. One is of `int` datatype and the other is a `varchar` datatype.

I am calling this procedure from another procedure, `sp2`.

Now, for some reason, I have added an additional parameter to `sp1`, also I modified the `varchar` datatype to `float` or `int`. This change will surely break `sp2`.

Is there any tool or process available inside SQL Server itself to change `sp2` also if `sp1` changed? I need to make it mandatory.

Is there any way for that, other than proper commenting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the `sys.sql_dependencies` catalog view - e.g. something like this:

```
SELECT 
    original.name, original.type_desc
FROM 
    sys.objects original 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.sql_dependencies dep ON dep.object_id = original.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects ref ON dep.referenced_major_id = ref.object_id
WHERE
    ref.Name = 'sp1'
```

This would list all objects in your database that somehow *reference* the `sp1` stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I know that I can check with sql dependencies  command. I was just checking, is there any other way which I can restrict or give warning to the user for modifying the child sp, while modifiying the parent  sp?

Comment: @RajaramanSahasranaman: no, I think the `sys.sql_dependency` is the way to go - and there's not a second or third option for this task